# Texturing Riva's Dress From Project Splatoon 3 By Alexis Pflaum

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

Using some concept art, I am trying to create this character's dress in Blender 3.0.0. So far, I've come very close to the original design, but it is at this point that I've hit a brick wall and I'm not sure what else I could connect in my Shader Editor to make this closer to the desired result. I'd appreciate some help in getting me closer to the original art. Thank you for being a great community.

Artwork by Alexis Pflaum, https://www.artstation.com/artwork/k4PeYz
Player00__M_Body, Armature, and other mesh featured here are made by Nintendo, ripped by the Models Resource.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty cool designs, neat style. Personally I'd try to draw some of these textures instead, seems better for things like the detailing on her jacket for example. Either way I wanted to give this a try and I cobbled this together:

[image: screenshot]

I think you won't get much out of the brick texture, the voronoi texture seems closer to what you need here. I used a Glossy BDSF for the line pattern since it looks like some of the bits are lit. I recommend setting the colours to 'Standard' in 'View Transform' under 'Color Management' in the render settings, if you haven't done so already. Will make it easier to try and get the same or similar colours from the reference.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it!